# Yii2 How to pass php array data into highcharts

Tags: javascript, php, highcharts, yii2

I am using Yii2 extension [miloschuman/yii2-highcharts](https://github.com/miloschuman/yii2-highcharts) for charts and get confused passing php array into hightcharts.

**My Array Values**

```
Array
(
    [Power Electronics] => 14.00
    [Introduction to Programming] => 3.92
    [Data base Management System] => 3.28
    [Object Oriented Analysis and Design] => 1.96
)
```

Now simply what I want to add this data to my highcharts I am passing above array like my below code.

**FROM MY HIGHCHARTS CODE**

```
'series' => [
    [
        "name" => "Exam Results",
        "data" => $course_data,
        'dataLabels' => [
            'enabled' => true,
            'rotation' => -90,
            'color' => '#FFFFFF',
            'align' => 'right',
            'format' => '{point.y:.1f}', // one decimal
            'y' => 10, // 10 pixels down from the top
            'style' => [],
            'fontSize' => '13px',
            'fontFamily' => 'Verdana, sans-serif',
        ],
    ],
],
```

I have already try many things but not get any success I wanted output like [this charts](https://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-rotated-labels).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to call `json_encode` function with mentioned array passed as an argument? Here is the code:

```
<?php
$data = [
    ['Power Electronics', 14.00],
    ['Introduction to Programming', 3.92],
    ['Data base Management System', 3.28],
    ['Object Oriented Analysis and Design', 1.96],
];

echo json_encode($data);
```

[EDIT]

You can also try to use `SeriesDataHelper` feature. There is information about using it in the documentation, here is the link: https://github.com/miloschuman/yii2-highcharts/blob/master/doc/examples/series-data-helper.md#using-numerically-indexed-data

Here is example code:

```
use miloschuman\highcharts\SeriesDataHelper;

$data = $data = [
    ['Power Electronics', 14.00],
    ['Introduction to Programming', 3.92],
    ['Data base Management System', 3.28],
    ['Object Oriented Analysis and Design', 1.96],
]

'series' => [
    [
        "name" => "Exam Results",
        "data" => new SeriesDataHelper($course_data, ['0:name', '1:y']),
        'dataLabels' => [
            'enabled' => true,
            'rotation' => -90,
            'color' => '#FFFFFF',
            'align' => 'right',
            'format' => '{point.y:.1f}', // one decimal
            'y' => 10, // 10 pixels down from the top
            'style' => [],
            'fontSize' => '13px',
            'fontFamily' => 'Verdana, sans-serif',
        ],
    ],
],
```

Comment: This array will be encoded by widget (at PHP level), if you encode data here, string will be passed as `data` in `Highcharts.chart()` options.

Comment: I still don't see the point. If you have array with correct format, you don't need to use `SeriesDataHelper` or encode to JSON manually. Passing array directly should be enough - it will be encoded by Yii helper to the format similar from [example](https://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-rotated-labels).

Comment: Please refer to documentation of that wrapper, where you can find a lot of specific informations about that.

Answer (score 0):

According to docs your array has invalid format. It should look like his:

```
$data = [
    ['Power Electronics', 14.00],
    ['Introduction to Programming', 3.92],
    ['Data base Management System', 3.28],
    ['Object Oriented Analysis and Design', 1.96],
];
```

You can fix this with simple foreach:

```
$newData = [];
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    $newData[] = [$key, $value];
}
```

Comment: this one not works for me hide the charts bar, and displaying nothing on screen.